# cloudant index: count number of unique users per time period

Tags: mapreduce, lucene, couchdb, cloudant, nosql

A very similar post was made about this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31105250/select-distinct-count-cloudant-couchdb). In cloudant, I have a document structure storing when users access an application, that looks like the following:

`{"username":"one","timestamp":"2015-10-07T15:04:46Z"}`---| same day 
`{"username":"one","timestamp":"2015-10-07T19:22:00Z"}`---^
`{"username":"one","timestamp":"2015-10-25T04:22:00Z"}`
`{"username":"two","timestamp":"2015-10-07T19:22:00Z"}`

What I want to know is to count the # of unique users for a given time period. Ex:

`2015-10-07 = {"count": 2}` *two different users accessed on 2015-10-07*
`2015-10-25 = {"count": 1}` *one different user accessed on 2015-10-25*
`2015 = {"count" 2}` *two different users accessed in 2015*

This all just becomes tricky because for example on 2015-10-07, **username: one** has two records of when they accessed, but it should only return a count of 1 to the total of unique users.

I've tried:

```
function(doc) {
    var time = new Date(Date.parse(doc['timestamp'])); 
    emit([time.getUTCFullYear(),time.getUTCMonth(),time.getUTCDay(),doc.username], 1);
}
```

This suffers from several issues, which are highlighted by Jesus Alva who commented in the post I linked to above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a better way of doing this, but off the top of my head ...

You could try emitting an index for each level of granularity:

```
function(doc) {
    var time = new Date(Date.parse(doc['timestamp'])); 
    var year = time.getUTCFullYear();
    var month = time.getUTCMonth()+1;
    var day = time.getUTCDate();

    // day granularity
    emit([year,month,day,doc.username], null);

    // year granularity
    emit([year,doc.username], null);
}

// reduce function - `_count`
```

Day query (2015-10-07):

```
inclusive_end=true&
start_key=[2015, 10, 7, "\u0000"]&
end_key=[2015, 10, 7, "\uefff"]&
reduce=true&
group=true
```

Day query result - your application code would count the number of rows:

```
{"rows":[
  {"key":[2015,10,7,"one"],"value":2},
  {"key":[2015,10,7,"two"],"value":1}
]}
```

Year query:

```
inclusive_end=true&
start_key=[2015, "\u0000"]&
end_key=[2015, "\uefff"]&
reduce=true&
group=true
```

Query result - your application code would count the number of rows:

```
{"rows":[
  {"key":[2015,"one"],"value":3},
  {"key":[2015,"two"],"value":1}
]}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize I could emit multiple types from the same view. Quick question ---- what's "\u0000" & "\uefff" for?

Comment: They represent small and large unicode values.  It's basically means include every value for this attribute.

Comment: ah! like a little wildcard, I like it. I think the last thing is what does "inclusive_end" do? I'm going to mark this question as solved, thanks by the way!!!

Comment: Nevermind, I noticed it's a flag for including the end key value